How to extrude a certain triangle in a mesh in three.js
Description:
My three.js scene is based upon a selection tool in which if we click and drag over the mesh it colors the triangles of the mesh red, I want to create a function that when runs checks the mesh.geometry.attributes and if it finds a triangle with red color it extrudes that triangle.
I am not good at attribute transformation and modification so I would love to get an explanation as well as how to perform this action in detail.
Furthermore, here is the selection part:

The red part is the selected area, I want to perform the extrusion like this:


Thanks in advance for the help!
What I tried:
I tried multipying and adding the normal of the triangle and then triangulating the edges but seem to get errors or just scattering of all the triangles inside the mesh.

This seems like an interesting problem... I've experimented with this a bit. I was thinking about two approaches to this.

Extrude individual parts of the model using the .fromBufferAttribute method, which seems to be what you meant.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.fromBufferAttribute

I was also thinking about dividing the model sections in Blender... Because from what I can see from your pictures, you mean specific parts of the model (e.g. Tooth 1, Tooth 2, Tooth 3, etc.), if I understand correctly. Which seems to be good for some form of presentation or something like that, where you intersect specific areas of the model to accentuate a particular area, either through color or by modifying vertices. Then, once you've made the entire model with the specific (named) sections you're interested in, we can work with them using .getObjectByName.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName
As for the first option, because the second one requires preparing a model, I will leave it. Although the logic is similar in general terms. So I approached it this way:

I set the wireframe for our duck to make specific, intersected places more visible.
I calculate the normal vector of the triangle.
I moved the vertices along the normal vector to create extrude effect (you can set colour of course as well)

You can look at this as well:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry

I used Raycaster to intersect part. So that should help avoid situation what you (probably) meant here:


…scattering of all the triangles inside the mesh.


Then call extrudeTriangle with the intersected triangle.
I set touch event as well to check how it works in mobile.

Function responsible for extrusion:
function extrudeTriangle(intersect) {
    const face = intersect.face;
    const geometry = intersect.object.geometry;
    const vertices = geometry.attributes.position;
    const a = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(vertices, face.a);
    const b = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(vertices, face.b);
    const c = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(vertices, face.c);
    const normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    THREE.Triangle.getNormal(a, b, c, normal);
    const extrusionDistance = 1;
    a.addScaledVector(normal, extrusionDistance);
    b.addScaledVector(normal, extrusionDistance);
    c.addScaledVector(normal, extrusionDistance);
    vertices.setXYZ(face.a, a.x, a.y, a.z);
    vertices.setXYZ(face.b, b.x, b.y, b.z);
    vertices.setXYZ(face.c, c.x, c.y, c.z);
    vertices.needsUpdate = true;
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
}
function handleInteraction(event) {
    let clientX, clientY;
    if (event.type === 'touchstart') {
        clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
        clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;
    } else {
        clientX = event.clientX;
        clientY = event.clientY;
    }
const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouse = new THREE.Vector2(
        ((clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * 2 - 1,
        -((clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * 2 + 1
    );
    const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        extrudeTriangle(intersects[0]);
    }
}
document.addEventListener('click', handleInteraction);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleInteraction);

https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/pen/rNgydxp
You can look on this approach as well, I mean to extrude, let say, smooth surface. To get that you need custom shader material and apply raycasting logic.
https://github.com/FarazzShaikh/THREE-CustomShaderMaterial#readme
I think this will be helpful as well
https://threejs-journey.com/lessons/wobbly-sphere-shader#variables

I will try this approach thanks for the answer, but I will need further guidance because as I said, I am not so good at morphing geometries. Also, your codepen isn't working. I suppose it's because of a typo or something

@AshhadDevLab Now should works, I mean pen.

So where is intersect.face coming from. Cause I am using the color of the faces to figure out which triangles to extrude
